# Apple validation url

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I Upload a new version in app store connect to validate my app.

the first step is to validate the server URL.

Always apple return " **Error message after URL check**".

The URL does not work for the Apple test.

despite he **works fine for me on the simulator and the iPhone device**.

Comment: Your URL should meet all requirements from Apple. What's the error message you get.

Comment: 1- Can you please tell me about the URL requirements for Apple to check if there is something missing.

2- When runnig the application I get sometimes the error 502 : bad Gatweway 
but for Apple they just can't access to the URL and neither service of the backend.

Comment: Can you give more info like when exactly you are hitting this error, may be some pseudo code.

Comment: I hit this error from the home page when calling a simple web service by a get httpRequest so when Apple try to connect with this service to the app they cannot even enter like they are bloqued.
Note that when we test with our device or with emulator the request succeed and we enter to app.But the problem with Apple , with every ipa we publish they  refused because they fail to connect to the request.
Have you any idea if there is some configuration required or some proxy setting or somthing else to allow apple connect to the app.

Comment: Is the issue reproduced on your local device if you install the production build from TestFlight?

Comment: I didn't try TestFlight , can you tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You may just to go TestFlight section of your app in iTunes / Apple connect, and follow the steps on your screen.